# Running final function after stopping a loop seems to have a time difference in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script that will show me running data when running on my treadmill because the display panel is broken. It's going to use GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi, so whenever the belt on the treadmill goes around, it can have a metal piece that shorts pins (they act as a button). It calculates speed depending on how fast the belt went around.

This means time is very important here. I've set up a loop in `rev_counter()` that gets the time and then when the "button" is pressed, it records the time again. Just to test it while I'm writing this program, I've simulated a button press with `sleep()`. I set it to `1.27841272276` seconds because this would be the time the belt would go around for a 7:30-minute mile pace. I've been trying to get it as close to that pace as possible.

I have gotten it to work pretty well. It is right on or maybe one second off while showing the info in the middle of the workout. The problem is, when I end the workout with `CTRL+C` so it goes to the results, the average mile pace ends up being off. It should be 7:30-7:31, but it ends up being 7:34-7:36. I'm pretty sure the time gets offset between when I stop the `rev_counter()` loop and when it calculates the results in `results()`. For some reason, when I ran the `update_display()` function in `rev_counter()` with `Thread`, it seemed to help. Could stopping in the middle of this loop be causing a problem? Why does only `results()` and not both `rev_counter()` and `results()` not get the time issue?

Here is my Python script:

```
import math
import os
import time
# from gpiozero import Button
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

# belt_button = Button(2)


def display(original_time=None, total_distance=None, current_speed=None, prev_rev_time=None):
    os.system('clear')
    print('Current Workout Information')
    print('')
    if original_time is None:
        print(f'Time elapsed: --:--:--')
        print('')
        print('Distance')
        print(f'Miles: --')
        print(f'Kilometers: --')
        print('')
        print('Current Speed')
        print(f'M/H: --')
        print(f'KM/H: --')
        print('')
        print('Pace')
        print(f'Mile: --')
        print(f'Kilometer: --')
    else:
        seconds_elapsed = prev_rev_time - original_time
        time_elapsed = increment(seconds_elapsed)
        mi = total_distance / 5280
        km = total_distance / 3280.84
        mph = current_speed / 1.46667
        kmph = current_speed * 1.09728
        min_mi = 60 / mph
        min_km = 60 / kmph
        mi_pace_min = math.floor(min_mi)
        mi_pace_sec = round((min_mi * 60) % 60)
        if mi_pace_sec < 10:
            mi_pace_sec = f'0{mi_pace_sec}'
        km_pace_min = math.floor(min_km)
        km_pace_sec = round((min_km * 60) % 60)
        if km_pace_sec < 10:
            km_pace_sec = f'0{km_pace_sec}'
        print(f'Time elapsed: {time_elapsed}')
        print('')
        print('Distance')
        print(f'Miles: {round(mi, 2)}')
        print(f'Kilometers: {round(km, 2)}')
        print('')
        print('Current Speed')
        print(f'M/H: {round(mph, 2)}')
        print(f'KM/H: {round(kmph, 2)}')
        print('')
        print('Pace')
        if current_speed == 0:
            print(f'Mile: 0')
            print(f'Kilometer: 0')
        else:
            print(f'Mile: {mi_pace_min}:{mi_pace_sec}')
            print(f'Kilometer: {km_pace_min}:{km_pace_sec}')


def increment(seconds_elapsed):
    seconds_elapsed = math.floor(seconds_elapsed)
    h = seconds_elapsed // 3600
    m = (seconds_elapsed // 60) % 60
    s = seconds_elapsed % 60
    if h < 10:
        h = f'0{h}'
    if m < 10:
        m = f'0{m}'
    if s < 10:
        s = f'0{s}'
    return f'{h}:{m}:{s}'


def rev_counter():
    revolutions = 0
    prev_rev_time = 0
    original_time = time.time()
    try:
        while True:
            prev_rev_time = time.time()
            # GPIO stuff
            # sleep(0.25)
            # belt_button.wait_for_press()
            sleep(1.27841272276)
            rev_time = time.time()
            revolutions += 1
            update_display(original_time, prev_rev_time, rev_time, revolutions)
            # Alternate code
            # thread = Thread(target=update_display, args=(original_time, prev_rev_time, rev_time, revolutions))
            # thread.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        os.system('clear')
        total_distance = 15 * revolutions
        results(original_time, prev_rev_time, total_distance)


def update_display(original_time, prev_rev_time, rev_time, revolutions):
    # feet * rev count
    # 15 = Length of my treadmill in feet
    total_distance = 15 * revolutions
    # feet / second
    rev_seconds = rev_time - prev_rev_time
    current_speed = 15 / rev_seconds
    display(original_time, total_distance, current_speed, prev_rev_time)


def results(original_time, prev_rev_time, total_distance):
    try:
        os.system('clear')
        seconds_elapsed = prev_rev_time - original_time
        time_elapsed = increment(seconds_elapsed)
        print('Workout Results')
        print('')
        if total_distance == 0:
            print(f'Total time: {time_elapsed}')
            print('')
            print('Distance')
            print(f'Miles: 0')
            print(f'Kilometers: 0')
            print('')
            print('Average Speed')
            print(f'M/H: 0')
            print(f'KM/H: 0')
            print('')
            print('Average Pace')
            print(f'Mile: 00:00')
            print(f'Kilometer: 00:00')
        else:
            average_speed = total_distance / seconds_elapsed
            mi = total_distance / 5280
            km = total_distance / 3280.84
            mph = average_speed / 1.46667
            kmph = average_speed * 1.09728
            min_mi = 60 / mph
            min_km = 60 / kmph
            mi_pace_min = math.floor(min_mi)
            mi_pace_sec = round((min_mi * 60) % 60)
            if mi_pace_sec < 10:
                mi_pace_sec = f'0{mi_pace_sec}'
            km_pace_min = math.floor(min_km)
            km_pace_sec = round((min_km * 60) % 60)
            if km_pace_sec < 10:
                km_pace_sec = f'0{km_pace_sec}'
            print(f'Total time: {time_elapsed}')
            print('')
            print('Distance')
            print(f'Miles: {round(mi, 2)}')
            print(f'Kilometers: {round(km, 2)}')
            print('')
            print('Average Speed')
            print(f'M/H: {round(mph, 2)}')
            print(f'KM/H: {round(kmph, 2)}')
            print('')
            print('Average Pace')
            print(f'Mile: {mi_pace_min}:{mi_pace_sec}')
            print(f'Kilometer: {km_pace_min}:{km_pace_sec}')
        print('')
        input('Exit ')
        os.system('clear')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        os.system('clear')


def main():
    os.system('clear')
    while True:
        try:
            print('AC Treadmill Workout Program')
            print('')
            input('Start Workout ')
            display()
            rev_counter()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('\n')
            print('Quitting... ')
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To run this program without any issues, run it in a Unix environment or Windows if you change all the `os.system('clear')` lines to `os.system('cls')`. Also make sure to run it in the terminal because my IDE (PyCharm) doesn't allow it to clear even when I set the TERM environment variable.

Comment: `results` calculates based on the whole elapsed time and is probably more accurate. `update_display` calculates based on the last revolution time which excludes especially the time needed by the `update_display` call itself.

Comment: Possible solution would be to use two threads as you already mentioned. Personally I would run a second thread which only enters the time stamps (not time spans) when the button is pressed in a list or queue while the main thread calculates and displays the results based on the data.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Not sure what you mean by time stamps and not spans because I look up Python time stamps and it shows `time.time()`. Also, when I hear time stamp, I think of the full date and time, but I don't think I would need that. I'm trying to redo how I calculate and display the results

Comment: I honestly don't know how to make the system you're talking about either

Comment: With time stamps I just meant the values returned by `time.time()`. With time spans I meant the difference of two time stamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using `Thread` and it got it to work the best it will probably work. Later, I'm going to convert the program to C++ so it has better performance and have a GUI and all sorts of stuff.

Here is what it ended up looking like:

```
import math
import os
import time
from gpiozero import Button
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

belt_button = Button(2)

# 15 is the length of my belt in feet
belt_length = 15


def display(original_time=None, total_distance=None, current_speed=None, prev_rev_time=None):
    os.system('clear')
    print('Current Workout Information')
    print('')
    if original_time is None:
        print(f'Time elapsed: --:--:--')
        print('')
        print('Distance')
        print(f'Miles: --')
        print(f'Kilometers: --')
        print('')
        print('Current Speed')
        print(f'M/H: --')
        print(f'KM/H: --')
        print('')
        print('Pace')
        print(f'Mile: --')
        print(f'Kilometer: --')
    else:
        seconds_elapsed = prev_rev_time - original_time
        time_elapsed = increment(seconds_elapsed)
        mi = total_distance / 5280
        km = total_distance / 3280.84
        mph = current_speed / 1.46667
        kmph = current_speed * 1.09728
        min_mi = 60 / mph
        min_km = 60 / kmph
        mi_pace_min = math.floor(min_mi)
        mi_pace_sec = round((min_mi * 60) % 60)
        if mi_pace_sec < 10:
            mi_pace_sec = f'0{mi_pace_sec}'
        km_pace_min = math.floor(min_km)
        km_pace_sec = round((min_km * 60) % 60)
        if km_pace_sec < 10:
            km_pace_sec = f'0{km_pace_sec}'
        print(f'Time elapsed: {time_elapsed}')
        print('')
        print('Distance')
        print(f'Miles: {round(mi, 2)}')
        print(f'Kilometers: {round(km, 2)}')
        print('')
        print('Current Speed')
        print(f'M/H: {round(mph, 2)}')
        print(f'KM/H: {round(kmph, 2)}')
        print('')
        print('Pace')
        if current_speed == 0:
            print(f'Mile: 0')
            print(f'Kilometer: 0')
        else:
            print(f'Mile: {mi_pace_min}:{mi_pace_sec}')
            print(f'Kilometer: {km_pace_min}:{km_pace_sec}')


def increment(seconds_elapsed):
    seconds_elapsed = math.floor(seconds_elapsed)
    h = seconds_elapsed // 3600
    m = (seconds_elapsed // 60) % 60
    s = seconds_elapsed % 60
    if h < 10:
        h = f'0{h}'
    if m < 10:
        m = f'0{m}'
    if s < 10:
        s = f'0{s}'
    return f'{h}:{m}:{s}'


def rev_counter():
    revolutions = 0
    prev_rev_time = 0
    original_time = time.time()
    try:
        while True:
            prev_rev_time = time.time()
            sleep(0.25)
            belt_button.wait_for_press()
            rev_time = time.time()
            revolutions += 1
            thread = Thread(target=update_display, args=(original_time, prev_rev_time, rev_time, revolutions))
            thread.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        os.system('clear')
        total_distance = belt_length * revolutions
        results(original_time, prev_rev_time, total_distance)


def update_display(original_time, prev_rev_time, rev_time, revolutions):
    # feet * rev count
    # 15 = Length of my treadmill in feet
    total_distance = belt_length * revolutions
    rev_seconds = rev_time - prev_rev_time
    # feet / second
    current_speed = belt_length / rev_seconds
    display(original_time, total_distance, current_speed, prev_rev_time)


def results(original_time, prev_rev_time, total_distance):
    try:
        os.system('clear')
        seconds_elapsed = prev_rev_time - original_time
        time_elapsed = increment(seconds_elapsed)
        print('Workout Results')
        print('')
        if total_distance == 0:
            print(f'Total time: {time_elapsed}')
            print('')
            print('Distance')
            print(f'Miles: 0')
            print(f'Kilometers: 0')
            print('')
            print('Average Speed')
            print(f'M/H: 0')
            print(f'KM/H: 0')
            print('')
            print('Average Pace')
            print(f'Mile: 00:00')
            print(f'Kilometer: 00:00')
        else:
            average_speed = total_distance / seconds_elapsed
            mi = total_distance / 5280
            km = total_distance / 3280.84
            mph = average_speed / 1.46667
            kmph = average_speed * 1.09728
            min_mi = 60 / mph
            min_km = 60 / kmph
            mi_pace_min = math.floor(min_mi)
            mi_pace_sec = round((min_mi * 60) % 60)
            if mi_pace_sec < 10:
                mi_pace_sec = f'0{mi_pace_sec}'
            km_pace_min = math.floor(min_km)
            km_pace_sec = round((min_km * 60) % 60)
            if km_pace_sec < 10:
                km_pace_sec = f'0{km_pace_sec}'
            print(f'Total time: {time_elapsed}')
            print('')
            print('Distance')
            print(f'Miles: {round(mi, 2)}')
            print(f'Kilometers: {round(km, 2)}')
            print('')
            print('Average Speed')
            print(f'M/H: {round(mph, 2)}')
            print(f'KM/H: {round(kmph, 2)}')
            print('')
            print('Average Pace')
            print(f'Mile: {mi_pace_min}:{mi_pace_sec}')
            print(f'Kilometer: {km_pace_min}:{km_pace_sec}')
        print('')
        input('Exit ')
        os.system('clear')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        os.system('clear')


def main():
    os.system('clear')
    while True:
        try:
            print('ASHER Treadmill Workout Program')
            print('')
            input('Start Workout ')
            display()
            rev_counter()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('\n')
            print('Quitting... ')
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue you're experiencing might be related to the fact that when you interrupt the rev_counter() loop with a keyboard interrupt , the KeyboardInterrupt exception is caught, and the results() function is called. However, the update_display() function is not called in the interrupt scenario.
To address this, you can modify your code to ensure that update_display() is called before the results() function when a keyboard interrupt occurs. Here's a modified

```
def rev_counter():
    revolutions = 0
    prev_rev_time = 0
    original_time = time.time()
    try:
        while True:
            prev_rev_time = time.time()
            # GPIO stuff
            # sleep(0.25)
            # belt_button.wait_for_press()
            sleep(1.27841272276)
            rev_time = time.time()
            revolutions += 1
            update_display(original_time, prev_rev_time, rev_time, revolutions)
            # Alternate code
            # thread = Thread(target=update_display, args=(original_time, prev_rev_time, rev_time, revolutions))
            # thread.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        os.system('clear')
        total_distance = 15 * revolutions
        update_display(original_time, prev_rev_time, rev_time, revolutions)
        results(original_time, prev_rev_time, total_distance)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't do anything

Comment: Try answers you make on your own before you actually post it. How do you know if it works if you don't test it yourself first?